# Pycharm: Correct type hints for wrapped function with decorator provided parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

### The Problem

I've defined a wrapper to handle the lifecycle of a stateful object: in this case a database `Session` object.

When the wrapper is used, it's expected that the wrapped function will accept a `session` parameter of type `Session` that is provided by the decorator. After that, any code using the wrapped function should be oblivious to the fact that a `session` is being provided at all.

With that in mind, the IDE type hint should omit any mention of a `Session` being used by the wrapped function.

### A Partial Solution

Here's some example code that works both with `MyPy` and `Pylance`, but not with `PyCharm`:

```py
import functools
from typing import TypeVar, Callable, cast
from typing_extensions import ParamSpec, Concatenate
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy import text

from my_database_setup import SessionLocal


_P = ParamSpec("_P")
_R = TypeVar("_R")


def with_session(fn: Callable[Concatenate[Session, _P], _R]) -> Callable[_P, _R]:
    """
    Will handle a `session` for the wrapped function, also removes the `session` type annotation

    Works with pylance and mypy
    """
    fn.__annotations__.pop('session', None)  # type: ignore

    @functools.wraps(fn)
    def wrapper(*args: _P.args, **kwargs: _P.kwargs) -> _R:
        session = SessionLocal()
        result = fn(session, *args, **kwargs)
        session.close()
        return result

    return wrapper


@with_session
def test_with_session(session: Session, /, number: int):
    res = session.execute(text(f"select {number}"))
    return res


test_with_session(number=1)
```

As you can see below, this results in the correct type hint in `VSCode` with `Pylance`:

[image: Correct type hint given in VSCode with Pylance]

However in `PyCharm`, we still see the `session` type hint:

[image]

### The Question

Is it possible to have `PyCharm` show the correct type hint for the `test_with_session` function? If so, how would you go about doing it?

Bonus: Is it possible to get `MyPy`, `PyCharm` and `Pylance` all working together, showing the correct type hint and checking for the correct type?

#### Notes

- The version of `PyCharm` shown is (at the time of asking) the most recent version of `PyCharm`: `PyCharm 2023.1.1 (Community Edition)`